Does the solutions yielded by augmented Lagrange function fulfill equality constraints?
Consider the following optimization problem,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x}\ & f(x),\\
s.t.\ &g(x)=0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with the smooth functions~$f(x),g(x)$,
which can be transformed into $\min_{x,\lambda}L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+\lambda g(x)$. So, if I employ Newton's method or gradient descent method to obtain solutions $x^*,\lambda^*$, then must $g(x^*)=0$ hold? And why?
